# Is it acceptable, actually encouraged, to post self-solved questions/answers?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

I really dislike having to solve the same problem more than once. Often though, I will encounter the same particularly bad bug that I have solved before but completely forgot the solution. I'll end up spending hours resolving it. I'm sure this is not a unique experience to just me.

Would it be acceptable to post the question/bug on stackoverflow, and immediately post your (working) solution?

For one, this saves me from having to solve it again in the future. Secondly, if other people encounter the same problem, the solution is available.

Comment: Well, yes. Otherwise they wouldn't have that self-answer feature.

Comment: With some caveats. See [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Note that it's *really* hard to self answer a question *well*.  Many people seem to think it's easy, and it's not, it's a lot harder, so be prepared to spend a fair amount of time and effort if you want both the question an answer to be of high quality and well received by the community.

Comment: For one thing, if you're calling it a bug, make sure you're writing a question and not a bug report.

Comment: I would hope so, I've self answered the only two questions I've asked (one intentionally, one as I just found the answer after posting, before anyone else posted). If anything, it just means that you get very few votes on it (as people tend to skip answered questions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, very much so, that's why there's the link at the bottom of the question box saying "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style", with a link to [this advice page](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

But you have to make sure the *question* is good quality - you need to put as much effort into writing a good question for it as for the answer.

Comment: There's also a related Badge! If that's not an encouragement, what is?